# CJK Characters are returning ▯ when prining to PDF using mPDF

Tags: php, regex, mpdf

I am trying to create a PDF from CJK Characters by using mDPf.

The problem is is that when the characters are printed out onto the PDF itself,  ▯ are being printed in place of the CJK characters.

Any suggestions? Below is a snippet of my code

```
$pdf=new mPDF('en','A4','','DejaVuSansCondensed',$template->margin_left,
      $template->margin_right,$template->margin_top,$template->margin_bottom,
      $template->margin_header,$template->margin_footer);

$pdf->setAutoFont();
$pdf->SetHTMLHeader($header);
$pdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer)
$pdf->writeHTML($printable);
if($task == 'pdf'){
    $pdf->Output($file_name, "D");
```

Comment: You should probably edit your post to show us the code you're using to do this. But, have you set your character encoding anywhere for the PDF?

Comment: Sorry! Will know for next time.

The character encoding is set and i am able to view it in and around the system. (As in, I can print the CJK characters out to a blank page or to anywhere I want)

I should maybe say that I think the problem is is that the m/PDF does not have the characters available to understand what it is being asked to print. There was a work around for this. However, the PDF will then be 14MB minimum. --> Which is not ideal

Cheers!

Comment: While your computer system might be able to handle the characters fine, mPDF might need you to explicitly set the encoding when you're creating the PDF, or something your passing to mPDF might be converting the encoding and giving you the odd characters.

Comment: Sorry for the first line.... couldnt edit it so that it would display nicely! Cheers for the advice that you have given so far :)

Comment: It could be that the autofont it's chosing doesn't support the characters. See [here](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=329) and [here](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=347)

Comment: Thanks for the links! So i've had a read of them but the problem still happens even with the little tweak i have made which is .

  $pdf->setAutoFont(AUTOFONT_ALL);.

  "Use SetAutoFont() to automatically detect these languages. AutoFont inspects the HTML code and inserts a span element to mark text which is auto-detected".

$printable is definitely HTML.

Comment: Sorry, I'm all out of ideas at this stage. You might be better off trying the mPDF forums.

Comment: Yeah me too XD 

But thanks anyway!

How do i formally thank you on stack? give you likes and what not?

Comment: No need to do any of that. But if you do find the answer, please do come back and answer your own question :)

Answer (score 4):

I am using v7.0 and solved this problem by using this constructor:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'ja+aCJK']);
```

Also, don't concatenate literal strings in your PHP (like HTML tags) with CJK strings before sending them to `WriteHTML()`, send the CJK strings to `WriteHTML()` by themselves.

Answer (score 1):

FIX FOUND!

in your config.php. Scroll down/search for 
$this->useAdobeCJK = false;

set this now to true;

Answer (score 1):

I am currently generating my PDF file using the CJK(Chinese, Japanese, Korean) font characters embedded in the mPDF v6.1.

It's working for me with the following settings.

**This is the file that you instantiate your mPDF object:**

```
$this->mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8');
$this->mpdf->useAdobeCJK = true;
$this->mpdf->allow_charset_conversion = true;
$this->mpdf->CSSselectMedia = 'mpdf';
```

**In the CSS file that I do:**

```
html {
    font-family: "Helvetica", "sun-exta", "unbatang";
}
```

**Check your mpdf/config_fonts.php file to see all the available fonts in:**

```
$this->fontdata = array(
...
)
```

**For more details, check the official documentation.**

https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/fonts-in-mpdf-6-x.html#using-cjk-fonts-in-mpdf

*I have accessed the official documentation on July 20th, 2017*

Answer (score -1):

```
require_once '../Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php';
                $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
                    'mode' => '-aCJK',
                    'margin_left' => 32,
                    'margin_right' => 25,
                    'margin_top' => 27,
                    'margin_bottom' => 25,
                    'margin_header' => 16,
                    'margin_footer' => 13,
                    'tempDir' => '/tmp',
                    'autoScriptToLang' => true,
                    'autoLangToFont' => true
                ]);
        
                $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
                $html = '定价和供应情况可能会发生变化';
        
                $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
                echo $mpdf->Output();
                exit;
```